# Which is the secure storage services in Azure?

Tags: azure, cloud

I want to store very high confident keys in azure cloud.

Among File, Table, Queue, Blob which storage service is most secure option?

And also which is most suitable?

Comment: Azure Key Vault might be the best choice

Comment: yes, you can use the Azure key vault, I have attached a link below for a guide on azure key vault.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Blob among File, Table, Queue, Blob
most suitable and most secure

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you want to store, all types are provided with a way to secure your files.

If you are looking a common way to secure any type of file storage **[`Keyvault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-whatis)** is the way to go!